# I hate word searches

Tags: knowledge, word-search

In the following grid are 38 nouns that have something in common. (I use "nouns" loosely, including, for example, noun phrases and proper nouns.) Their respective [enumerations](/a/45985) are: 4; 4; 4; 4; 4; 4; 4; 4; 4; 4; 5; 5; 5; 6; 7; 7; 7; 7; 7; 7; 2,6; 3,5; 5,3; 8; 3,6; 4,5; 9; 4,6; 5,5; 6,4; 7,3; 10; 10; 6,5; 6,6; 8,4; and 8-5.

[image: WDHYDMIYDESKGDRK / NIRMOIASAWCNNANC / RIOAYHUEERINIIOA / EOGCONEARGGLSLST / KSOHMBTRNCRNSABA / RTEDTEEISOENIRIO / AREYRLSTAHACKTGB / PAULEOIDAEERISSL / PWGTBDTGBKTYTURI / IBNTLRHAHESBBAMA / LEOOAFMNVTUAPAOS / IRTINIARDETBKMRB / HRNLLERIAHLYKCEB / PYELRLTSITNEDOIF / WOREDDNEIRFTSEBN / WOBLESUOMYEKCIMS]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Erm, I hate it to point it out to you, but *there are actually 37 (not 38) valid nouns in this wordsearch...* (but then you already knew that...)

The solved grid looks like this:

> [image: Solved wordsearch]

And the 37 nouns concealed within are (listed in the order of your enumerations):

> BATH, CONE, DESK, EYES, HAIR, NICK, PAUL, SINK, SOAP, TACK, BECKY, DRAIN, ELBOW, TONGUE, CRYBABY, DENTIST, ELLIOTT, KISSING, SINGING, SWEATER, DR FIELDS, ICE CREAM, STING RAY, SAILBOAT, MRS GIBSON, LIMA BEANS, AUSTRALIA, BEST FRIEND, NIGHT LIGHT, ALBERT MOYO, HERSHEY BAR, SKATEBOARD, STRAWBERRY, MICKEY MOUSE, PHILIP PARKER, ELEVATOR DOOR, RAILROAD TRAIN

What do these have in common? They all...

> ...appear in the children's book [*Alexander and the Terrible, Horrible, No Good, Very Bad Day*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_and_the_Terrible,_Horrible,_No_Good,_Very_Bad_Day) by Judith Viorst. (A full transcription of the words can be found [here](https://www.northiowa.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/ALEXANDER-AND-THE-TERRIBLE.pdf).)

Note that the leftover letters spell out a message, read from left to right and top to bottom:

> **WHY DID I MISCOUNT THE NUMBER OF WORDS?**

To answer this:

> note that in the story itself, the main character makes his own miscount:
>
>   *At counting time [the teacher] said I left out sixteen. Who needs sixteen? I could tell it was going to be a terrible, horrible, no good, very bad day.*
>
>  And this is exactly what you have done yourself - fully intending to include it as the 38th word in your wordsearch **you've left out 'SIXTEEN'!**
>
>  I suspect that now as a result you are probably having your own *terrible, horrible, no good, very bad day*... (Which would also explain why - just like how in the story Alexander hates lima beans, kissing and his rail-road pajamas - you seem to be feeling some hate of your own towards wordsearches in the title!)

Comment: How can you infer a obbx given a bunch of words?? Are they distinctive enough?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis At first I just looked for any old nouns, but then after a while I spotted that many of my gaps were filled by rot13(anzrf - Orpxl, Cuvyvc Cnexre, Qe Svryqf, Zef Tvofba... Va snpg, gurfr ynfg guerr sryg fb qvfgvapgvir gung V gubhtug n Tbbtyr frnepu zvtug uryc - naq vg yrq zr fgenvtug gb guvf obbx, jurer V gura sbhaq nyy bs gur bgure jbeqf nccrnevat! Guvf gura urycrq zr cvacbvag gur ynfg jbeqf V jnf zvffvat, nf vg orpnzr pyrne gurer jnf n uvqqra zrffntr hfvat gur yrsgbire yrggref, naq riraghnyyl gur chmmyr jnf fbyirq!)

Comment: Thanks for the bounty @msh210 :)